# Creating/Manipulating a pandas dataframe from multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I need to create a dataframe with four columns for further processing. Each column has a range from 0-100 with increments of 1 (those are percentages). That's the easy part. The not-so-easy part (for me. for others probably rather trivial) is, that the checksum of each row always has to be 100. That obviously expands the number of rows from `100` to `100*100*100*100`.

For example:

```
100 0 0 0
99  1 0 0
99  0 0 1
87  4 5 4
...
```

I've tried creating four lists first

```
lstA = list(range(0, 101, 1))
lstB = list(range(0, 101, 1))
```

and then a df out of them, but i'm at a loss how i'm supposed to run that checksum operation on the dataframe, while also sorting the columns and appending the resulting additional rows accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the different possibilities for the first 3 values and compute the fourth one

```
out = []
for i in range(101):
    for j in range(101-i):
        for k in range(101-i-j):
            out.append([i, j, k, 100-i-j-k])
                
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

*NB. note that number of valid combinations is **176851**.*

Output:

```
          0  1  2    3
0         0  0  0  100
1         0  0  1   99
2         0  0  2   98
3         0  0  3   97
4         0  0  4   96
...     ... .. ..  ...
176846   98  2  0    0
176847   99  0  0    1
176848   99  0  1    0
176849   99  1  0    0
176850  100  0  0    0

[176851 rows x 4 columns]
```